# How can I use an align environment flush right?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

Is there an option analogous within the `align` environment to the left align for right align, i.e. `fralign`.

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} % Instead have [freqn].
 %\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools} Something that will also work for mathtools as well.

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} % Would be fralign* instead.
    \sin 2x &= 2sin x\cos x \\ 
    \cos 2x &= \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x &
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "fl" in `fleqn` is "fixed length", while in `flalign` is "full line". Would you better explain your needs?

Comment: @egeg: Werner fulfilled what the question asked. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without specifying a package option to [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), you can use the `flalign[*]` environment and add some (unused) alignment characters `&` to typeset the equation flush right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\begin{flalign*}
  &&\sin 2x &= 2\sin x\cos x \\ 
  &&\cos 2x &= \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The adjustment to the lengths `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip` (both set to `0pt`) was merely to reduce the gap above the flushed equation. This may not be necessary in the document in general.

Comment: i'm not sure that `flalign*` is necessary; `align*` might be sufficient.  (but i'm not able to check from my present location.)

Comment: +1..So double `&` characters are needed to flush right instead of one `&`.

Comment: @barbara: You are correct, once `fleqn` has been set as an option to either `amsmath` or `mathtools` in the preamble, then the align environments will automatically be pushed left. For clarification.