# Equation number at the right of first line with multline

Tags: equations, numbering, multline

This is very similar to [A vertically centered equation number on a multline environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61195/a-vertically-centered-equation-number-on-a-multline-environment), but the answers won't apply to my case it seems.

I have

```
\begin{multline}
X = \\
LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG
\end{multline}
```

and like how the output looks without a line number. Now I want to add a line number to the right, but the second line is too long. How do I put it in the first line (to the right!)?

I know about `\raisetag`, but I would prefer an exact solution. My second line has a non-trivial height.

Edit: I should add that LOOOOOOOOOONG is nearly as long as my text width.

Edit: This is a more appropriate example:

```
\begin{multline}
X = \\
\framebox[\linewidth]{LONG}
\end{multline}
```

Edit: Once again a more elaborate example to show that egreg's answer does not answer my question. My use case is an integral expression that **I do not want to break**. It does not matter how it looks or what its contents is. Its line is pretty damn close to the available linewidth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\begin{document}

This works fine:
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[t]%
X = \\%
\framebox[\dimexpr.9\linewidth\relax]{some expression shorter than the next}%
\end{multlined}%
\end{equation}%


Note the equation number in this harder case:
\begin{equation}%
\begin{multlined}[t]%
    X = \\%
    \framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.666666pt\relax]{long expression that I do not want to break}%
\end{multlined}%
\end{equation}%

This solves the equation number problem, but messes up horizontal positioning. It actually goes over the right border:
\begin{equation}%
    \begin{multlined}[t]%
        X = \\%
        \mathmakebox[.9\width][l]{%
            \framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.666666pt\relax]{long expression that I do not want to break}%
        }%
    \end{multlined}%
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `multlined` from `mathtools` (that loads `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
X =  \\
LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG
\end{multline}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[t][.9\displaywidth]
X =  \\
LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[t]
X =  \\
LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If the first line is short, I'd prefer the third option. But in my documents the number stays with the last line.

[image]

A different approach, for a really long line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
& X= && \\
&&& \mathmakebox[0pt][r]{%
  \framebox[\displaywidth]{\dotfill long expression that I do not want to break\dotfill}
  \hspace{-1.8em}
}
\notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

You have to hide a the part that would overlap the space for the equation number

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that I nice idea. I did not know about [t]. However, when using LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG instead of LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG, the number jumps to a third line of the equation, although there is enough space on the first line. It depends on the length of the second line and \textwidth - I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @bers Yes, of course; if a line is too long, the equation number is shifted down and `multlined` is just a single block. It would be shifted also with `multiline`.

Comment: You got it. Now my second line happens to be too long, so I still need a solution :) My first line is not too long, so the number should always fit. Yes, `multline` has the same problem as your solution, but this does not mean 1) that this is what I want, nor 2) that this is how it has to be. I want a short first line, left-aligned, with an equation number on the right; and a very long second line, potentially filling the line, right-aligned, with no equation number.

Comment: @bers In tough cases, you can hide a portion of the last line by using something like `\mathmakebox[.9\width][l]{...}`. No automatic solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: `\mathmakebox[.5\width][c]{\framebox[\linewidth]{LONG}}` looks like it's working. I'll try further with that, thanks so far!

Comment: No, it doesn't really. `[c]` as well as `[l]` influence the positioning of the first line (not flush left any longer). But it's better than nothing.

Comment: @bers A real case could help.

Comment: I edited the question once more with an MWE. I do not see how my "real case" would add anything since I do not wish to break my integral expression.

Comment: Your last answer looks very nice, thank you. Could you explain what the value of 1.8em corresponds to? is that an exact solution? It seems to match perfectly at the right border. Is this some space which is reserved for the equation number?

Comment: @bers Pure luck.

Comment: Too bad, it seems this number depends on the length of the tag to be hidden.

Comment: Not working for me. In fact, the multlined is not recognized. It seems that mathtools is up and running.

Comment: @Hamid “Not working” is insufficient for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I use an align environment flush right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32121/how-can-i-use-an-align-environment-flush-right) and [Use flalign or alignat or align or similar environment to align to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/use-flalign-or-alignat-or-align-or-similar-environment-to-align-to-the-left) helped me come up with this (which I am quite happy with):

```
\begin{gather}
    \begin{flalign}
        & X = &
    \end{flalign}\\
    \begin{flalign*}
        && LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG
    \end{flalign*}  
\end{gather}
```

Edit: Putting everything together what egreg proposed (in particuar, `mathmakebox`, this is what I came up with.

```
\begin{align}
    & #1 \\
    & \mathmakebox[\displaywidth][r]{#2}\notag
\end{align}
```

Actually pretty simple. I doubt it can be much easier than this. egreg's solution has the drawback of not working with unknown tag widths, and I have not found how to get them from amsmath.

Comment: The vertical spacing is not optimal, so if anyone finds an alternative the spacing of which is closer to the `multline` solution, I'd be happy to accept that.

Comment: Just use *one* `flalign` environment, with `\notag` in the line you don't want the number in.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that before, but I was unable to get the alignment right then. I want first line flush-left, second flush-right, no matter how long they are. Having the two in a single `flalign` makes that the two lines cannot "overlap". Remember, the second line is long.

Comment: That's why I asked for a real case.

Comment: There is one in my MWE, the second one.

Comment: I see no real math formula.

Comment: This is true. It would involve me stripping down my example with custom page margins and convoluted formulae to create another MWE that would not teach anything more than the one I already created. What would be the added value of it having a formula instead of the box? If you like, just use \int LOOO...OONG until the line is filled. But my box achieves just that.