# How to put an equation number at the first line?

Tags: numbering, eqnarray

```
\begin{eqnarray} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
A & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

What this gives me: an equation number between the first and the second equation line.

I'm trying to put the equation number at the fist line (on the the right side).

I've looked at [Equation number at the right of first line with multline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226392/equation-number-at-the-right-of-first-line-with-multline) but unfortunately it doesn't help, because I have to have this equation written in `\eqnarray`.

Comment: don't use `split` in eqnarray, it is best to avoid `eqnarray` anyway but `split` is designed for use with ams alignments. just use `align` here, with `\notag` on the second line.

Comment: you should not be using `eqnarray` in the first place, use `align` then you done get the wrong spacing and other problems that comes with `eqnarray`. Why are you even combing `eqnarray` with `split`, you could just have left of `split` and put a `\notag` on the second line

Comment: @daleif Have to use \eqnarray. It is a mandatory obligation from my professor.

Comment: then simply remove split and use \nonumber on the second line (but your professor is wrong)

Comment: then send your professor this: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf, they should come into the 21 century. A lot of professors have not kept up with developments. I see this a lot in the manuscripts that I edit. Often they just don't know any better.

Comment: @daleif Will try to update him, but can't promise :) Good argument!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `align` instead of `eqnarray` and remove `split`. In general, always use `align` if possible, it is preferred to `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align} \label{eq1}
A &= \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2 \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

In case of `eqnarray` being mandatory, you can get around this with a bit of "ugly" code:

```
\begin{eqnarray} \label{eq1}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
A &{}={}& \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
  &{}={}& \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2 \notag
\end{eqnarray}
```

And you get the same result, but I strongly encourage you to update your professor as others have suggested, even this simple example can convince any person.

Comment: I don't know why @campa deleted his answer, I wrote mine at the same time but didn't submit until he removed his answer.

Comment: I removed mine because upon re-reading the question I noted that `eqnarray` is apparently required, so "don't use `eqnarray`" didn't strike me as a helpful answer `:-)` Then I started rewriting the answer with `eqnarray`, then the phone rang...