# How do I align a math environment to the right?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, hebrew, bidi

I'm trying to wrote a few math formulas, but they go left. The picture will explain: [image]

As you can see, the < signs are not in the same line. 
The code:

```
צד ראשון: \L{
\begin{eqnarray*}
2(i+1) & \leq & j+2\\
2i+2 & \leq & j+2\\
2i & \leq & j
\end{eqnarray*}
}צד שני:\L{
\begin{eqnarray*}
j+2 & \leq & 3(i+1)\\
j+2 & \leq & 3i+3\\
j & \leq & 3i+1
\end{eqnarray*}
```

I'm using LyX, anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `eqnarray` only aligns the symbols within the same display, the first one has larger formula on the left hand side.

Comment: Note it is impossible for anyone to run your code to debug any issues  as you provide no document, and no definition for `\L` (also it is better to use `amsmath` evironment `align*` rather than `eqnarray*`

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertinus}
% To make the output narrow enough to fit on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=11cm]{geometry}

\babelprovide[main, import=he]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
צד ראשון:
\begin{align*}
2(i+1) & \leq & j+2\\
2i+2 & \leq & j+2\\
2i & \leq & j
\end{align*}

צד שני:
\begin{align*}
j+2 & \leq & 3(i+1)\\
j+2 & \leq & 3i+3\\
j & \leq & 3i+1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hebrew sample]

Or at least, this aligns the equations to the right as you wanted.  I would probably tweak the alignment a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertinus}
% To make the output narrow enough to fit on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=11cm]{geometry}

\babelprovide[main, import=he]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
צד ראשון:
\begin{align*}
2(i+1) & \leq j+2\\
2i+2 & \leq j+2\\
2i & \leq j
\end{align*}

צד שני:
\begin{align*}
j+2 & \leq 3(i+1)\\
j+2 & \leq 3i+3\\
j & \leq 3i+1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample 2]

Both of these samples use the `bidi` feature of `babel` to align the equation blocks correctly for Hebrew, and the `align*` environment of `mathtools`. They also load a font family with Unicode support for both Hebrew text and math.

See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32121/how-can-i-use-an-align-environment-flush-right) for another way to flush equations to the right, and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/aligning-across-aligned-equation-blocks) to align equations in two separate blocks.

You might consider adding the option `\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}` if you want equation numbers to the left.